# Exploring blockchain use cases for real world problems

Tags: solidity, blockchain, solana

Wassup Guys, I hope you are well! I'm new into blockchain development. I have a few ideas but a lot of doubts, one of the doubts is if ethereum (solidity) or solana (rust) written contracts are a good fit for those ideas. One of the ideas is: a multi vendor marketplace for physical goods, let's say for example... Luxury goods. My goal with this idea would be to reduce the costs/fees that incur on sellers to sell their goods through the web, yet keeping the whole trade process reliable and fair, for both sellers and buyers. I thought about developing a solid escrow contract that would be initialized inside the marketplace when a potential buyer decides to buy something. The contract should cover the possible scenarios that could happen during the whole selling process such as fraud and scam allegations. In this case the marketplace would be the third party escrow manager and would take the final decision over such allegations, based on proofs or evidences. My goal wouldn't be to develop a decentralized application, but to reduce costs instead. Today any payment processor would charge at least 3% on each sale inside such marketplace besides another fees, and I wonder if crypto and blockchain technology couldn't help to reduce these costs. Do you guys have any insights if would be possible to develop an idea of this kind using any of these techs (eth or solana)? I got interested in ethereum/solidity because of the broad range of resources to learn, adoptability of the community, and the stable coins such as USDC and EURC that are available in the chain... I know the need to build trust over the sellers and buyers, for them to be comfortable with making business in the marketplace whereas the platform itself is the arbitrator of disputes, but that's just the nature of the business, every other successful marketplace went through this process of trust building. What are your guys thoughts?

Comment: I think the bottleneck here will be the system for confirming fulfillment of the terms of the contract.